# Accidentally overwrote /usr/local/include, what's the damage?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, sudo

I ran this command accidentally when I was trying to give Homebrew access to write some symlinks:

```
sudo install -d -o $(whoami) -g admin /usr/local/include
```

and I realized by the `-d` flag would create a new `include` directory.

Now the `/usr/local/include` directory is empty and I can't seem to find any obvious damage done to my system.

Could someone please tell me what usually is in `/usr/local/include` and what I should do to rebuild its content?

Comment: You can always re-download your OS version and run the install again. It won’t do any harm if you’re already running that version. It will replace files back to default such as this directory.

Comment: @Jahhein Do I need to back up (say with Time Machine) before doing that?

Comment: You should always have a backup with any device. But no, you don’t *need* to. You download it from the App Store and it’ll show up like any application and be deleted after running it again.

Comment: The reason you should have a backup is because it might change configurations you had previously. You might find that worse than the issue you have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base MacOS `/usr/local` is empty so `/usr/local/include` just contains what you  have installed.

So either

1. The best way restore from a backup
2. Delete /usr/local/* and reinstall Homebrew and any other files you have installed there.

Comment: Thank you! I think I did lose a few tools that I previously installed with Homebrew and that's pretty much it.